# How to pass image gotten from camera or gallery to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**1. User selects a button to either upload from gallery or capture from camera**

*From gallery*

```
    choose_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            // Sets the type as image/*. This ensures only components of type image are selected
            intent.setType("image/*");
            //We pass an extra array with the accepted mime types. This will ensure only components with these MIME types as targeted.
            String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,mimeTypes);
            // Launching the Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });
```

*From camera*

```
capture_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(UploadActivity2.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", createImageFile()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

**2. User selects a photo from gallery or capture from camera and the image is displayed in the current activity**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
............//grant permission codes here

//If it is from gallery
if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) { 
     Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
     String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
     cursor.moveToFirst();   
     int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
     String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
     cursor.close();

     //Display image with glide
     Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(imgDecodableString).into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? 
     super Bitmap> transition) {
                        display_image.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        display_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }    
}

//If request is from camera
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        switch (requestCode){
            case 0:
                //Display image in current activity 
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(cameraFilePath)
                        .into(display_image);
                /*display_image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(cameraFilePath));*/
                display_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }

}
```

**3. I have a 'NEXT' button and when clicked I want to transfer the image displayed (Gotten from either the Gallery or Camera) to another activity, I havn't written a code for passing the image yet**

```
next_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity2.this, UploadActivity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**4. I want to know the best way to do this without affecting image quality and memory because in the next activity (UploadAcitivity3), I will be uploading the image passed to the server and saving in a directory**

Comment: Put your full code on pastbin so we can understand where your getting capture image and picked image uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps to achieve this:

**Option - 1:** If you want to pass multiple images then use below:

- **Step - 1:** Store the selected images path in an `ArrayList` like below:

```
private ArrayList<String> selectedImages = new ArrayList<>();

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {

    ............//grant permission codes here

    //If it is from gallery
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        ....

        String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        selectedImages.add(imgDecodableString);
    }

    //If request is from camera
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        selectedImages.add(cameraFilePath);
    }
}
```

- **Step - 2:** From `onClick` set the selected images list as `extras` to `intent`

```
next_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity2.this, UploadActivity3.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("SELECTED_IMAGES", selectedImages);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

- **Step - 3:** Retrieve the selected images from `intent` in `UploadActivity3` like below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ....

    ArrayList<String> selectedImages = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("SELECTED_IMAGES");

}
```

---

**Option - 2:** If you want to pass single image then use below:

- **Step - 1:** Store the selected image path like below:

```
private String selectedImage;

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {

    ............//grant permission codes here

    //If it is from gallery
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        ....

        String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        selectedImage = imgDecodableString;
    }

    //If request is from camera
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        selectedImage = cameraFilePath;
    }
}
```

- **Step - 2:** From `onClick` set the selected images list as `extras` to `intent`

```
next_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity2.this, UploadActivity3.class);
        intent.putExtra("SELECTED_IMAGE", selectedImage);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

- **Step - 3:** Retrieve the selected images from `intent` in `UploadActivity3` like below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ....

    String selectedImage = getIntent().getStringExtra("SELECTED_IMAGE");
    Glide.with(this).load(selectedImage).into(image_view);
}
```

Comment: Any String constant like `SELECTED_IMAGES`

Comment: Thank you. I tried to display the image in the uploadActivity3 using glide. Its not displaying. I got **Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: [/storage/emulated/0/imagename.png]** for image selected in gallery and **Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: [file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/imganename.jpg]** for images captured with camera.?? I used **Glide.with(this)
                .load(selectedImages)
                .into(image_view);**

Comment: Let me clear, at a time how many images do you want to pass to `uploadActivity3`?

Comment: In my solution `selectedImages` contains list of images. If you pass single image then use `Glide.with(this) .load(selectedImages.get(0)) .into(image_view);` in `uploadActivity3`

Comment: He want to pass only one image either gallery or captured image. @ibramazin you have to use Glide.with(this) .load(selectedImages.get(0)) .into(image_view);  like this...

Comment: Just 1. And Also I tried to use without glide **image_thumb.setImageURI(Uri.parse(selectedImages));** I got error **parse(java.lag.string) in Uri cannot be applied to (java.util.arrayList<java.lang.string>)**

Comment: In that case please use `selectedImages.get(0)` instead of `selectedImages`

Answer (score 1):

You can send the image path through `Intent`

```
next_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity2.this, UploadActivity3.class);
        intent.putExtra("path", imagePath);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

You already have image path for capturing image is `cameraFilePath`

and for gallery image `imgDecodableString`.

Declare `String imagePath;`   as class variable and assign them in `onActivityResult.`

```
imagePath = imgDecodableString;//For Gallery


imagePath = cameraFilePath;//For Capture image
```

Receive path in `UploadActivity3.class`

```
String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
```

Use this path in second activity as you want.